# Java fetch Hierarchical data from table and generate a tree

Tags: java, microservices

I'm setting up hierarchical for angular tree view  from database table. I have Category Table.
[Category Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vySEP.png)

I want the output in the following format

```
[{
    "category_id": 1,
    "category_name": "Action",
    "categoryParentId": 0,
    "categoryDto": [{
        "category_id": 4,
        "category_name": "Classical",
        "categoryParentId": 1,
        "categoryDto": [{
            "category_id": 3,
            "category_name": "Instrumental",
            "categoryParentId": 4,
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Every Category has a column `category_parent_id` which can zero if its a parent or else it will some other `category_id`.

I have the java code in which I want to fetch this data form a json tree like structure which will then be used by Angular tree view to generate the necessary UI component.

Category Repository

```
    @Repository
    public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {

        List<Category> findByCategoryParentId(int categoryParentId);
    }
```

Category Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "content_category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int category_id;

    private String category_name;

    @Column(name="category_parent_id")
    private int categoryParentId;
```

CategoryDto

```
public class CategoryDto {

    private int category_id;

    private String category_name;

    private int categoryParentId;

    private List<CategoryDto> categoryDto;
```

I have tried setting the dto using recursion but with no success. I am able to get the data to depth of one level but not beyond that.

My method implementation.

```
List<CategoryDto> categoryDto=new ArrayList<CategoryDto>();
@Override
    public List<CategoryDto> getAllParentCategories(int category_parent_id) {
        List<CategoryDto> categoryDtoList = new ArrayList<CategoryDto>();
        List<Category> categoryList = categoryRepository.findByCategoryParentId(category_parent_id);
        for (int i = 0; i < categoryList.size(); i++) {
            CategoryDto dto = new CategoryDto();
            dto.setCategory_id(categoryList.get(i).getCategory_id());
            dto.setCategory_name(categoryList.get(i).getCategory_name());
            dto.setCategoryDto(printTree(categoryList.get(i).getCategory_id()));

            categoryDtoList.add(dto);

        }

        return categoryDtoList;
    }


    public List<CategoryDto> printTree(int id) {


        List<Category> categoryList = categoryRepository.findByCategoryParentId(id);
        if (categoryList.size() > 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < categoryList.size(); i++) {

                CategoryDto dto = new CategoryDto();
                dto.setCategory_id(categoryList.get(i).getCategory_id());
                dto.setCategory_name(categoryList.get(i).getCategory_name());
                if (categoryRepository.findByCategoryParentId(categoryList.get(i).getCategory_id()).size() > 0) {
                    dto.setCategoryDto(printTree(categoryList.get(i).getCategory_id()));
                }
//              else {
//                  dto.setCategoryDto(null);
//                  categoryDto.add(dto);
//              }
            }
            return categoryDto;
        } else {
            return categoryDto;
        }

    }
```

`getAllParentCategories()` is called with `parent_is` as and post that every `parent_id` fetched from db is passed as param

My recursive method is not working as  expected.

Output with error message "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unterminated string literal at line 1 column 79905 of the JSON data"

```
[{"category_id":1,"category_name":"Action","categoryParentId":0,"category_uniq_id":null,"category":null,"categoryDto":[{"category_id":4,"category_name":"Classical","categoryParentId":0,"category_uniq_id":null,"category":null,"categoryDto":[{"category_id":4,"category_name":"Classical","categoryParentId":0,"category_uniq_id":null,"category":null,"categoryDto":[{"category_id":4,"category_name":"Classical","categoryParentId":0,"category_uniq_id":null,"category":null,"categoryDto":[{"category_id":4,"category_name":"Classical","categoryParentId":0,"category_uniq_id":null,"category":null,"categoryDto":[{"category_id":4,"category_name":"Classical","categoryParentId":0,"category_uniq_id":null,"category":null,"categoryDto":[{"category_id":4,"category_name":"Classical","categoryParentId":0,"category_uniq_id":null,"category":null,"categoryDto":[{"category_id":4,"category_name":"Classical","categoryParentId":0,"category_uniq_id":null,"category":null,"categoryDto":[{"category_id":4,"category_name":"Classical","categoryParentId":0,"category_uniq_id":null,"category":null,"categoryDto":[{"category_id":4,"category_name":"Classical","categoryParentId":0,"category_uniq_id":null,"category":null,"categoryDto":[{"category_id":4,"category_name":"Classical","categoryParentId":0,"category_uniq_id":null,"category":null,"categoryDto":
```

Comment: "My recursive method is not working as expected." - in such cases please describe what you expect _and_ what happens instead (in some detail, i.e. more than " I am able to get the data to depth of one level but not beyond that." - where exactly do you fail?).

Comment: `List<CategoryDto> categoryDto=new ArrayList<CategoryDto>();` is that defined on the class level? That doesn't seem wise and prone to errors. When a method like `printTree()` (that name is misleading btw since the only thing it prints seem to be statements meant for debugging) returns a list that list should be created somewhere inside that method (or a method it calls). Otherwise you'll very likely run into side effects when calling that multiple times (such as cycles in your tree). - That actually very like one of your problems or even your main problem so fix that please.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Yeah I guess List<CategoryDto> categoryDto=new ArrayList<CategoryDto>(); at the class level is the problem. I will try creating it may be inside the method .